# Basic question about definition of Chern classes

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Apologies if there is something I missed with a quick internet search, but why do we define Chern classes for complex vector bundles (instead of real vector bundles for example)?

If we define chern classes using homotopy theory, finding a natural transformation from between ${\rm Vect}_{n}(\cdot)$ and $H^{i}(\cdot;R)$ in the case of real vector bundles reduces to computing the cohomology ring of the base space of the universal real $n$-plane bundle (which I think is the real Grassmannian) by the Yoneda embedding, just like in the complex case. Is the only reason why we don't consider the real case is because the cohomology in the real case is more complicated?

I've stated the question using topology, but an answer from any viewpoint (for example 
using curvature) is also appreciated.

Comment: There's no need to work with Chern classes over $\Bbb{C}$: read the Wikipedia article a bit more thoroughly. Perhaps one reason that $\Bbb{C}$ is the most common field for the vector bundles is that complex line bundles are classified by maps to $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$, which is of more interest than $\Bbb{R}P^\infty$, let alone the more general Grassmanians, to the physicists who motivated much of this field.

Comment: There are also characteristic classes for real bundles that are widely used. They go under the name "Stiefel-Whitney classes" and "Pontryagin classes".

Comment: See the discussion here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16632/stiefel-whitney-classes-over-integers

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Chern classes are only defined for complex vector bundles.

Comment: Perhaps most generally, for any topological group $G$ and any cohomology theory $E$, you have "characteristic classes" given by elements of $E^*(BG)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think (but I could be wrong) one of the reasons that Chern classes are used for complex vector bundles and not real ones is that the space of sections of a complex vector bundle is usually a finite dimensional vector space, thus giving rise to more of an algebraic structure. And since Chern classes measure how tuples of sections fail to be linearly independent, Chern classes would fail to capture much information for real vector bundles since real smooth vector bundles have way too many sections, i.e., their sections are never finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: A real vector bundle is also a finitely generated module over continuous functions (at least for M compact).

Comment: I think I should say that global sections of a complex vector bundle are often finite dimensional vector spaces, not finitely generated modules over functions.

Comment: Dear dezign, On a compact complex manifold, the space of holomorphic sections of a holomorphic vector bundle will be finite dim'l.  However, this won't be true of the smooth sections, and nevertheless one considers Chern classes associated to complex bundles on compact smooth manifolds that are not necessarily complex manifolds, and one considers Stiefel--Whitney classes of real bundles on smooth manifolds.  So I'm not sure how strong this justification is.  Regards,